# Developer - if I need to review code of junior developers, is it reason for a raise?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, software-development

I am middle developer, not having to interact with junior developers.
My boss also said I am middle because in our organization you are senior if you are
allocated a junior developer ("allocated" was vaguely defined though).

Now, at my workplace they are considering taking juniors, this might mean
me at least reviewing their code from time to time. Or depending on the level of
juniors more close supervision.

My question is, is such situation a reason for asking for a raise in salary?

Comment: To a very real extent, you're going about this the wrong way - if you're looking for more responsibilities / a raise, ask your boss "what do I need to do to get a raise?"

Comment: Developers review other developers code, it seems like your duties might be expanding, if youo are a middle developer is you.  However, a Senior developer, would typically review a junior developer's code. So the question you ask, is does a Senior developer with one Junior developer, come with a pay increase? You will likely be told that pay increase comes later when you have more than one.

Comment: I'm wondering why your juniors are not doing code reviews.

Comment: What are your seniority and role expectations right now?

Comment: Go with Philip's advice. And also, interview with other companies. The reasoning he originally gave you is kind of vague and overly simplistic. Do not trust it.

Answer (score 8):

> If I need to review code of junior developers, is it reason for a raise?

**There would be no salary raise.**

Software engineers review one another's code all the time. It's part of the job.

The 2 main purposes of the code reviews are:

1. To improve the quality of the code and products.
2. To improve software development skills of the team members.

There is no salary raise just for reviewing your coworkers' code regardless of what level you and your coworkers are (i.e.  junior/mid/senior/staff).

Answer (score 6):

You can always ask! But no, it is not my experience that this would be worthy of a raise. Now if you began directly managing a junior dev, that's a different story.

What I would do is take on this new responsibility with a positive attitude and go above and beyond to help the juniors when you get involved. That way, next time a performance review rolls around, you can point to how well you're doing at pseudo-managerial tasks as reason to ask for a promotion or expansion of official responsibilities, either one of which **would** come with a raise.

Comment: May you elaborate what you mean with "directly managing a junior dev" ?

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, is such situation a reason for asking for a raise in
> salary?

You can always ask for a raise. If you feel this change in responsibilities is significant enough, ask for one.

As long as you don't make a habit of asking for raises too often, it's unlikely to hurt you.

Answer (score 0):

Code reviews are a normal part of any developer's job in any serious project.

As a medior you should already know that and be used to it. Juniors often aren't doing it as much because they're not expected to have the experience to do it properly, but they'll still be expected to take part.